# Run Intel Fortran binary with Python

Tags: python, bash, fortran, intel-fortran

I am trying run a Fortran binary from within a Python script on a Mac. From the command line the Fortran binary works fine but when I run it with `os.system` or `subprocess.open` in Python then I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libimf.dylib
Referenced from: /Path/To/Binary
Reason: image not found
```

The Fortran binary is build with Intel Fortran. Any idea what goes wrong here?

EDIT:

I have these environmental variables set in my ~/.bash_profile which does not help:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.083/mac/compiler/lib"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016.1.111/mac/compiler/lib"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries/mac/lib"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016.0.083/mac/compiler/lib"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016.1.111/mac/compiler/lib"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries/mac/lib"
```

I am running the python script from the terminal on my Mac. I tried printing from Python with

```
print os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH']
print os.environ['DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH']
```

which both give the following error:

```
KeyError: 'DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH'
```

EDIT:

I tried running another binary with `os.system` in my Python code and that works fine.

Comment: Probably a LD_LIBRARY_PATH problem, check if this is set in your command line and in your subprocess.

Comment: are you running python from your bash shell directly?   You should edit the question with details instead of in comments btw

Comment: You should check your environment from within the python script with os.environ

Comment: Does running a fotran binary (executable) in any way differ from running another kind of binary?

Answer (score 0):

I expect the problem is because there is no `'DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH'` key in Python's `os.environ` dictionary; your profile setting of `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` seems fine, but Python isn't receiving it.

On my yosemite system, if I source the Intel-supplied `compilervars.csh` script to set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` (resulting in a value of `/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016.1.111/mac/compiler/lib:...`) then the following succeeds for me

```
$ cat test.f90 && ifort test.f90 && python -c "import os; os.system('./a.out');"
print *, 'Hello World!'
end
 Hello World!
```

(From bash you would presumably utilize the `compilervars.sh` script instead to do this.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely the new System Integrity Protection (SIP) built into Mac El Capitan. Basically, when you run a protected process, such as a python script, DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is not passed to the script.

The best solution is recompiling your Fortran binaries in a manner that avoids the use of dynamic libraries. Alternatively, you can prevent this problem by disabling SIP (probably not recommended) as described here:

[Macworld Article](http://www.macworld.com/article/2986118/security/how-to-modify-system-integrity-protection-in-el-capitan.html)

You can find more information about this issue by searching "DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH SIP"